# XML CultureInfo loading data incorrectly

Tags: c#, xml, cultureinfo

I'm loading floats from an XML document.

For example from the following line:

```
  <Attack name="Sword Slash" damage="10.0" stat="Strength" multiplier="2.0" />
```

If I read this and then parse it to a float, the damage is 100 instead of 10.0, and the multiplier is 20 instead of 2.0 aswell. I think this is because of problems with CultureInfo (not sure on this).

I tried fixing it by changing the line that reads the data from:

```
this.damage = float.Parse(reader.Value);
```

To:

```
this.damage = float.Parse(reader.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

However, this does not seem to fix anything.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
this.damage = float.Parse(reader.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, it would probably make things easier if you used [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx) instead of manually parsing the XML.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Will this ensure it will work on any PC? (different languages etc.)

Comment: @anthonytimmers, yes, the invariant culture is always the same (as the name implies). It's associated with the English language, but not with a specific country. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx